# Android: su pm install "это же обновлённое приложение"

Tags: android, exec, runtime, su

Всем доброго времени суток. Помогите сделать обновление приложения. Вот код:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su" + "\n");
OutputStream i8 = p.getOutputStream();
i8.write(("pm install -r -d -g " + myApkFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\n" + "exit" + "\n").getBytes("UTF-8"));
i8.flush();
p.waitFor();
```

Он умеет устанавливать и обновлять **только другие** приложения.

Допустим, APK-файл моего приложения лежит на карте памяти, куда я его закачал с компьютера. Устанавливаю приложение. Затем заменяю этот APK-файл на, к примеру, APK-файл какой-нибудь скачанной игры с Play Market. Запускаю своё приложение и в течение 10 секунд игра, скачанная с Play Market'а установлена. Но если я заменяю старый APK-файл своего приложения на обновлённый APK-файл своего приложения, даже если с другой более высокой версией (`android:versionCode` и `android:versionName`) в отличие от моего приложения, но таким же `package`, то ничего не происходит. Команда установки `pm install ...` просто игнорируется. `exitValue` всегда возвращается 0, независимо от того, установилось ли приложение.

Answer (score 1):

1. Создать файл на карте памяти (например, "log.txt"), в который должно быть записано всё с `p.getErrorStream()`. Это нужно, чтобы примерно понять, в чём ошибка заключается.
2. В логах "log.txt" (см. пункт 1) я увидел ошибку, что параметра `-d` и `-g` не существует в команде `pm install`, о которых я узнал [тут](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/shell.html). Из-за того, что я их указал система не понимала, что я от неё хочу и просто возвращала `exitValue` 0, что кстати странно).
3. Файл `myApkFile` **не должен быть глубже, чем** `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`! Это очень важно. Даже `su` не поможет `pm` достать его, к примеру, из `mContext.getFilesDir()`.